# Setting interface card into monitor mode

Tags: shell

How come this code does not work, gives errors in line 8 and 12

> ./monitor.sh: line 8: [iface: command not found
>   ./monitor.sh: line 12: [iface: command not found

iface should be the variable, here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

ip link set wlan1

echo Please enter your wifi interface of choice
read iface

if [iface == wlan1]
then
   iw wlan1 set monitor control
   echo wlan1 is set in monitor mode
elif [iface == wlan0]
then
   iw wlan0 set monitor control
   echo wlan0 is now set in monitor mode
else
   echo No card was put into monitor mode, try again
fi
```

Comment: Because the syntax of those lines is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $iface after you read in line 6
and if format is incorrect

should be:

```
if [ $iface == "wlan1" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`if [iface == wlan1]` should be `if [ $iface == wlan1 ]`. Both the spaces and the sigil are required.